# Enum parameter function and switch optimization

Tags: c++, c, optimization

How to optimize such code:
ENUM_ELEM are elements of an enum, i would like to avoid such switch

```
short int f(short int b){
    switch(b){
        case ENUM_ELEM1 : return -12;
        case ENUM_ELEM2 : return 0;
        case ENUM_ELEM3 : return 12;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to optimise it for?  Run time performance, readability, concision?  If performance, what have you observed about the current performance that you think could be improved on?

Comment: Post the definition of the enum. Optimization may depend on their values, and how many values there are.

Comment: I downvoted your question, because you didn't post the definition of the enum, even after I asked for it, even after it contains 3 values only! What difficulty do you've posting it?

Answer (score 2):

If your `ENUM_ELEM#` are in the low range, then you could use a table, and use the enum value as the index into the table to get the returned value.

But I can imagine that some smart compiler may optimize the code this way by itself ...

Don't forget the three rules of optimization: measure, measure, measure.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options:

If your enum values are consecutive default values (i.e.: 0,1,2) - make a table:

```
int translate[ENUM_ELEM3] = {-12,0,12};
return translate[ENUM_VALUE];
```

Or, `#define` them as -12,0,12, you pass a `short int` anyway, not an `enum`.

IIRC new standard (c++0x) allows `enum` values to be negative, check if your compiler supports it, then you won't have a problem at all.

Comment: New C++0x standard? I believe old standards do also allow enum values to be negative!

Comment: @Ajay - I'm not sure it explicitly allowed it. Here's the discussion on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159034/are-c-enums-signed-or-unsigned

Answer (score 0):

If your enums are compact, use a lookup table

Answer (score 0):

If this is about code quality/maintainability w.r.t. OOP, you might want to look into the refactoring "replace conditional with polymorphism".

In case of performance optimization (which you shouldn't care about until you've verified the *real* bottlenecks of your application, and also you shouldn't care about them prematurely), you could use a good old lookup table, simply let it there like it is <sup>0</sup>, or (again) let it there like it is because your CPU is less than 15 years old <sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>0</sup>  compilers already optimize many switch statements (but you might want to look at what your compiler actually does for you)

<sup>1</sup> speculative execution, branch prediction and your branch target buffer might very well be better than you and the compiler

Answer (score 0):

Provided that value of ENUM_ELEM1 is negative, value of ENUM_ELEM2 is zero and value of ENUM_ELEM3 is positive.

Then you may want to *refuctor* towards readability by the following:

```
static final short unPos = (short)(1 << 15);

static short f(short b)
{
    return (short)(b == 0 ? 0 : (b &= unPos) == unPos ? -12 : 12);
}
```

Please notice that I implemented in Java, but I guess you will find the corresponding syntax for the language of your choice.