# Sign of C++ Enum Type Incorrect After Converting to Integral Type

Tags: c, visual-c++, enums, c++03

My understanding is that C++ enumerations are converted to integral types according to Integral Promotion. And during Integral Promotion, we should try converting a value to `int` first and if the value cannot be represented by an `int`, `unsigned int` should be used:

C++03 conv.prom:

> 2) .... An rvalue of an enumeration type (7.2) can be converted to an rvalue
>   of the first of the following types that can represent all the values
>   of the enumeration (i.e. the values in the range bmin to bmax as
>   described in 7.2: int, unsigned int, long, or unsigned long.

But my testing in VC++2010 shows contradicting result:

```
enum {A1=60, A2=61,A3=63,A4=64,A5=66,A6=0xffffFFF1};
const bool b1 = A6 < A1;
//result b1=true;
```

`A6` is `0xffffFFF1` which should be an unsigned value (decimal 4294967281). And, since this value cannot be represented by an `int`, it should be converted to `unsigned int`. But clearly, when used in the comparison, `A6` was converted to -15. Why is it so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159034/are-c-enums-signed-or-unsigned

Comment: FYI it works as you'd expect on Clang 3.4.

Comment: I tend to disagree with all the answers in the supplied link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159034/are-c-enums-signed-or-unsigned. Enum is a distinct type having no sign.  When we use it in a context that requires signedness, we are talking about converting the enum to some integral type which is a well defined action. It is called Integral Promotion - nothing related to the underlying type of the enum.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug of MS VC++. I described it [here](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000056-000-0-0-1396345661)

Though the description is written in Russian you can translate it into English using for example google service translate.

Also there is a defect relative to enumerations in the C++ Standard itself. I also described it 
[here](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000060-000-0-0-1360057169)

And one more reference relative to a discussion of enumerations (at this time in English) can be accessed [here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/uTfy9iOITko)